# Table values as gridview heading in asp.net mvc4

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want show the values of a column as gridview header in my MVC4 application.
Table looks like

Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
A   1       5
B   2   4
A       3
A           6

I want this table to look like below in a gridview

```
1   2   3   4   5   6
```

A   Y       Y       Y   Y
B       Y   Y

Can any one please help me to suggest any idea for this..

Thanks and regards
Divya

Comment: It would help if you format your sample data and results properly or even better, post `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements so that someone can actually set up your test case themselves with no effort.